# Setting new frame of subview not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, autoresize

I'm having trouble with `autoResizing`. First, I have a VC that's forced in landscape mode, and a that's subview added like this:

```
let upLeftArrow = UIImageView()

var height = CGFloat()
var width = CGFloat()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.height = self.view.frame.height
    self.width = self.view.frame.width

        upLeftArrow.image = UIImage(named: "upLeftArrow")
        upLeftArrow.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin
        upLeftArrow.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        upLeftArrow.frame = CGRectMake(0.2 * width, 0.17 * height, height * 0.0577 * 0.935, height * 0.0577)

    self.view.addSubview(upLeftArrow)
}
```

However, if I open this view when my phone is in portrait mode, and then use the function under to change the frame of the subview, my subview changes it frame like it's in portrait. This makes no sense to me since I've already declared the width and height variables and used them in my `viewDidLoad` function.

How I change the frame:

```
func changeFrame(){

    self.upLeftArrow.frame = CGRectMake(0.2 * width, 0.17 * height, height * 0.0577 * 0.935, height * 0.0577)

}
```

Please help me understand why this happens, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `view` bounds are not set in `viewDidLoad`. By default they are assigned the portrait orientation frame. So you should calculate your width/height in either `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Gandalf does that mean that all subviews should not be added in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, the best practice is to add subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. However you can add in `viewDidLoad` as well unless you are relying on `self.view` or device main screen `bounds` to calculate the frame.